# Single verb for "at the location most of the time"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am drafting an email in which I would like to convey that

> Dian Guang Zhou is there most of the time

but would like a more effecient way of conveying this idea.

I want the sentence to read like so: [Subject] [verb] [place pronoun].

I thought about frequent, but it makes the subject sound like a patron instead of an owner (and he is an owner). I wish I could say "he oftens there."

Comment: Your sentence is pretty efficient. Depending on exactly what is supposed to be meant by "is there most of the time," you might use *Dian Guang Zhou hangs out there.*

Comment: 'is usually there'?

Comment: Your sentence is already efficient. If you want to imply that people can come to Dian for assistance and he's there to help, then I would write _"Dian is available to assist customers most of the time during business hours."_ Instead of _"available"_ you can also use _"on hand"_. For ultimate efficiency, _"Dian is usually on hand"_.

Comment: @MartinKrzywinski Yes.  And to really drive home the distinguishing effect I could have said "Dian is the owner usually on hand."  Very good!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verb **frequent** can work here as a single word:

> Dian Guang Zhou frequents the art gallery.

Defined as

> to visit often; go often to; be often in: *to frequent the art galleries.* ([Dictionary.com #4](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/frequent))

Another verb that might be a little more edgy is **haunt**.

> Dian Guang Zhou haunts the art gallery.

Defined as

> to visit frequently; go to often: He haunted the galleries and bars that the artists went to. ([Dictionary.com #3](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/haunt?s=t))

With your updated clarification, you can say **He's often there** of, as spagirl said, **He's usually there**. But this doesn't give you the verb you requested. (You can also say **He often is there**, but this doesn't contract nicely to *He often's there*, which, apart from the apostrophe, is like your preference in your question.)

Comment: I like *frequents* - I didn’t think of that.  Or maybe even ***works*** there - which is probably closer to what OP is after.

Comment: I thought about frequent,  but it makes the subject sound like a patron instead of an owner (and he is an owner).  I wish I could say "he oftens there."

I might end up going with the colloquial: "he stay dyeuh"

Comment: @JonathanMuse - Can you add that information to the question? That is an important fact that most people will miss if it's only in the comments.

Comment: @CanisLupus So edited.

Comment: @JonathanMuse _Dyeuh_ is colloquial? In which language exactly? It's certainly not an English word I've ever come across…

Comment: @JonathanMuse If you're considering going colloquial, you could just come clean and admit "He owns da joint!"